# touch/mkdir seems to ignore default ACL

Tags: permissions, acl, mkdir, touch

I am pretty sure it is a stupid mistake but I can't seem to figure it out by myself, so please have a look.

I set up an ACL for the current folder like so:

```bash
zigbee2mqtt@nuc:/tmp/folder$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: zigbee2mqtt
# group: zigbee2mqtt
user::rwx
user:stack:r-x
user:zigbee2mqtt:rwx
user:milkpirate:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:stack:r-x
default:user:zigbee2mqtt:rwx
default:user:milkpirate:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
zigbee2mqtt@nuc:/tmp/folder$ id
uid=978(zigbee2mqtt) gid=977(zigbee2mqtt) groups=977(zigbee2mqtt)
```

so when I now create a folder/file in that folder like so:

```bash
zigbee2mqtt@nuc:/tmp/folder$ touch foo; mkdir bar
```

It results in the following permission on the folder `foo`:

```bash
zigbee2mqtt@nuc:/tmp/folder$ getfacl foo
# file: foo
# owner: zigbee2mqtt
# group: zigbee2mqtt
user::rwx
user:stack:r-x
user:zigbee2mqtt:rwx
user:milkpirate:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:stack:r-x
default:user:zigbee2mqtt:rwx
default:user:milkpirate:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

which looks fine so far.

But the ACL of the file then looks off:

```bash
# file: bar
# owner: zigbee2mqtt
# group: zigbee2mqtt
user::rw-
user:stack:r-x                  #effective:r--
user:zigbee2mqtt:rwx            #effective:rw-
user:milkpirate:rwx             #effective:rw-
group::---
mask::rw-
other::---
```

1. I would expect the `mask` to be `rwx` (desired).
2. Since `group` and `other` are `---` (desired) the permission in `ls -la` to be the same, but they are:

```bash
zigbee2mqtt@nuc:/tmp/folder$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwx---+  3 zigbee2mqtt zigbee2mqtt 4096 Jan 15 17:55 .
drwxrwxrwt  16 root        root        4096 Jan 15 17:59 ..
-rw-rw----+  1 zigbee2mqtt zigbee2mqtt    0 Jan 15 17:55 bar
drwxrwx---+  2 zigbee2mqtt zigbee2mqtt 4096 Jan 15 17:55 foo
```

but I would expect (and desire):

```bash
zigbee2mqtt@nuc:/tmp/folder$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwx---+  3 zigbee2mqtt zigbee2mqtt 4096 Jan 15 17:55 .
drwxrwxrwt  16 root        root        4096 Jan 15 17:59 ..
-rw-------+  1 zigbee2mqtt zigbee2mqtt    0 Jan 15 17:55 bar
drwx------+  2 zigbee2mqtt zigbee2mqtt 4096 Jan 15 17:55 foo
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, did some testing and all seems to work as desired, the result of `ls -la` does not seem to reflect the correct rights:

```bash
zigbee2mqtt@nuc:/tmp/folder$ sudo -u nginx -g zigbee2mqtt bash
nginx@nuc:/tmp/folder$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in the `ls` listing are the "traditional" permission bits, all you'd have in a system that doesn't support ACLs, and all that can be used by tools (or users!) that aren't ACL-aware.

The "traditional" group permission bits *don't* correspond to the owning group ACL, but to the ACL mask ([`acl(5)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html)):

> **CORRESPONDENCE BETWEEN ACL ENTRIES AND FILE PERMISSION BITS**
>
> The permissions defined by ACLs are a superset of the permissions
> specified by the file permission bits.
>
> There is a correspondence between the file owner, group, and other
> permissions and specific ACL entries: the owner permissions
> correspond to the permissions of the ACL_USER_OBJ entry. **If the ACL
> has an ACL_MASK entry, the group permissions correspond to the
> permissions of the ACL_MASK entry.**  Otherwise, if the ACL has no
> ACL_MASK entry, the group permissions correspond to the permissions
> of the ACL_GROUP_OBJ entry.  The other permissions correspond to
> the permissions of the ACL_OTHER entry.

What the mask does, is limit the permissions that can be granted by ACL entries for named users, named groups, or the owning group. In a way, you can think of the three sets of "traditional" permission bits as applying to 1) the owning user, 2) other explicitly defined users (without ACLs: members of a the owning group; with ACLs: those plus other named users or members of other named groups), and 3) everyone else.

The practical reasoning there is that if a user or program wants to make sure only the owner has write permissions to the file, something like `chmod go-w` still works to do that, *even without the actor knowing about ACLs*.

So, having it show `rwx` for the group in the `ls` listing is by design, since you have the `user:zigbee2mqtt:rwx` and `user:stack:r-x` ACL entries there. The `ls` output just hints that there are some others apart from the owning user who have read, write and/or execute permissions on the file. Setting the mask to `000` (with e.g. `chmod g-rwx` or the appropriate `setfacl` command) would make those ACL entries for `user:zigbee2mqtt` and `user:stack` ineffective.

---

When you create a file with `touch`, and see `mask::rw-` on it, that's because `touch` and most other tools create regular files with permissions `0666`, not `0777`, leaving the `x` bits off. Most files shouldn't be executable. Regardless of the ACLs, the permissions passed to the `open()` system call still count, the same as if the permissions were changed with `chmod()`.  Apart from leaving the `x` bits off, this allows a program to create private files by setting the permissions bits to `0600`.

Comment: Hey @ilkkachu sadly our comments seem to be gone, but I rewrote the question and tried to clarify a little. Could you have a look again?

Comment: @milkpirate, getting `mask::rw-` on the file is normal, since the file is likely to be created with the `x` bits off. (Note how you also got `user::rw-` even though the directory had `default:user::rwx`.). And again, what you see in the output of `ls -l` is not the `group::` permission bits, but the `mask::` bits.