# Why does setfacl affect filemode by turning on group-write

Tags: permissions, acl

I have a script that is used to re-apply ACLs on files and directories.  However it has the side effect of turning on Group Write permissions that I can not explain.  I have narrowed down the cause to one specific statement in the script by checking the permissions before and after every statement.

```
root@kompir:/tmp/perms# nl /apply-sec 
     1  #!/bin/bash
       
     2  targetbase=$1
     3  [ -z "$targetbase" ] && exit
     4  [ ! -d $targetbase ] && exit
     5  #set -x
       
     6  check_base() {
     7          # Debugging function - call it to view the current ACL and mode bits
     8          getfacl $targetbase
     9          ls -ld $targetbase
    10          echo ---------------------------------------------
    11  }
       
       
    12  # Remove any ACLs
    13  setfacl -R -b $targetbase
       
    14  # Set basic permissions
    15  chown -R owner $targetbase
    16  find $targetbase -type d -exec chmod 2755 {} \;
    17  find $targetbase -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
       
       
    18  # Set Default Mask
    19  setfacl -d -m m:rwx $targetbase
       
    20  # User1 with Default
    21  check_base
    22  setfacl -m u:user1:rwx $targetbase
    23  check_base
    24  setfacl -d -m u:user1:rwx $targetbase
       
    25  # User2 with Default
    26  setfacl -m u:user2:r-x $targetbase
    27  setfacl -d -m u:user2:r-x $targetbase
       
    28  # Apply recursively
    29  getfacl $targetbase | setfacl -R -M- $targetbase
```

The statement on line 22 turns on the group write mode bit (Which was turned off on line 16)

The output from the script is as follow, using some sample directories created for the purpose of testing.

```
root@kompir:/tmp/perms# /apply-sec perms1/
# file: perms1/
# owner: owner
# group: root
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

drwxr-sr-x+ 4 owner root 4096 Jun  9 09:20 perms1/
---------------------------------------------
# file: perms1/
# owner: owner
# group: root
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:user1:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

drwxrwsr-x+ 4 owner root 4096 Jun  9 09:20 perms1/
---------------------------------------------
```

Note that the group-write permission is turned back on the second time the debug function is called to show the mode.

Why does this happen, is this expected behaviour, and can it be avoided?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [touch/mkdir seems to ignore default ACL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729787/touch-mkdir-seems-to-ignore-default-acl)

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the group-write permission is turned back on the second time the debug function is called to show the mode.

It's not, see the output you got:

```
# file: perms1/
[...]
group::r-x
```

What you see in the output of `ls` is not the group permissions any more, but the ACL mask that limits what permissions the named user and group ACL entries can give.

See the [`acl(5)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html). Longer explanation in my earlier answer to
[touch/mkdir seems to ignore default ACL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/729787/170373)

Comment: How did I never know this?-  Thank you, this explains everything.